# the navigation with two key is not working in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

i have made a login and register pages with AUTH and it was working and after that ,I want to receive data from my database . so ,I change the if else statement after that the data match is working is not taking me to home page I tried some ways to fix it but it doesn't work
[error:Data Matched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaDLK.jpg)

so here we see the api is working
[my php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpaqN.png)

[my react code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naAD1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message in the screenshot **does not match** the message from the condition.

Try to change the condition as shown below:

```js
const {message} = responseJson;
if (typeof message === 'string' && message.toLowerCase().trim() === 'data matched') {
    // do navigation here
}
```

```js
const oldVerify = (responseJson) => (responseJson === 'Data Matched');

const newVerify = (responseJson) => (typeof responseJson === 'string' && responseJson.toLowerCase().trim() === 'data matched');

const cases = ['Data Matched', 'Data matched', 'data MATCHED', '  data matched ', 'data matched'];

cases.forEach((_case) => {
  console.log('======');
  console.log(`Case: "${_case}"`);
  console.log('Old verify:', oldVerify(_case));
  console.log('New verify:', newVerify(_case));
});
```

I advise you to publish your code in plain text in the future :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not work and in console log it give me the the first case two true , in other cases old is false , and new is true ,

Comment: @moniemHeraki what does your response handler look like now?

Comment: .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          responseJson.message;
          responseJson.userData;    ............... like this

Comment: @moniemHeraki why are you accessing response fields without assigning them anywhere? I have updated my answer

Comment: okey it work thanks so much , if can i ask you something if you can help , i was have one const for massage and one for data , now i have for massage how can i get the data from api for specific user ?

Comment: @moniemHeraki `const {message, userData} = responseJson;` or `const message = responseJson.message; const userData = responseJson.userData;`

Comment: @moniemHeraki if it works well, then you can mark my answer as a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237635/discussion-between-moniem-heraki-and-wowandy).